# Merging 2 data.frames, but skip/drop rows upon comparison of multiple fields

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, match

I have 2 data frames - the first is my actual data, which boils down to the length and weight of stuff, broken down by the age, size, and sex.

```
data <- "   AGE SIZE SEX LEN  WT
0   6.5     0    3   11
0   8.5     0    9   53
0  10.5     0    7   67
0   8.5     1    1    8"

data <- read.table(text=data, header=TRUE)
```

For my analysis, I need to add all of the possible combinations of age, size and sex, and assign values of 0 to len and wt.  I've generated a 2nd data.frame with all these possible values.  As an example, a subset of it looks like this:

```
#ages are "0", but they can range from 0 to ~20
#for any "SIZE", sex can be 0-2
filler <- "   AGE SIZE SEX LEN  WT
0   6.5     0    0    0
0   6.5     1    0    0
0   6.5     2    0    0
0   8.5     0    0    0
0   8.5     1    0    0
0   8.5     2    0    0
0  10.5     0    0    0
0  10.5     1    0    0
0  10.5     2    0    0"
filler <- read.table(text=filler, header=TRUE)
```

I am trying to merge these 2 data frames together, replacing the default, filler values with real data, where it exists, but retaining the filler data where no real data exists.

Essentially, if my data has the same combination of age, sex and size, then the corresponding row in my filler data should be discarded (ie replaced with the actual data).  The output I would like looks like the following.

```
AGE SIZE SEX LEN  WT
0   6.5     0    3   11  #data
0   6.5     1    0    0
0   6.5     2    0    0
0   8.5     0    9   53  #data
0   8.5     1    1    8  #data
0   8.5     2    0    0
0  10.5     0    0    0
0  10.5     0    7   67  #data
0  10.5     2    0    0
```

Maybe I'm just brain-dead this morning, but I've been checking out merge, which and match, but I'm just not quite getting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `expand.grid` to create your `filler` data frame, but containing purely the factor levels.

```
filler <- expand.grid(AGE=0:2, SIZE=seq(6.5, 10.5, by=2), SEX=0:2)
head(filler)
  AGE SIZE SEX
1   0  6.5   0
2   1  6.5   0
3   2  6.5   0
4   0  8.5   0
5   1  8.5   0
6   2  8.5   0
```

Then use `merge` to perform a right join, i.e. set `all.y=TRUE`:

```
z <- merge(data, filler, all.y=TRUE)
head(z)

  AGE SIZE SEX LEN WT
1   0  6.5   0   3 11
2   0  6.5   1  NA NA
3   0  6.5   2  NA NA
4   0  8.5   0   9 53
5   0  8.5   1   1  8
6   0  8.5   2  NA NA
```

Finally you can replace the `NA` values with 0.  Here is one of way doing this:

```
z[is.na(z)] <- 0
head(z)

  AGE SIZE SEX LEN WT
1   0  6.5   0   3 11
2   0  6.5   1   0  0
3   0  6.5   2   0  0
4   0  8.5   0   9 53
5   0  8.5   1   1  8
6   0  8.5   2   0  0
```

Comment: That was brilliant - thanks so much.  I'm not even going to tell you how much code I deleted upon discovery of the expand.grid() function.

Comment: Hey Andrie - Just curious about your seemingly needlessly complex for turning NAs to 0s.  Is there something wrong with `z[is.na(z)]<-0`?

Comment: No, that works too!  I'm sometimes too careful in treating data frames like arrays.  I'll modify my answer.

Comment: OK - it wasn't meant as criticism - I'm still learning R and have been using the method I posted everywhere.  I was just worried I'd been overlooking something important.  Cheers.